# show the function is uniformly ctns on the (2,8)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

[show the function f(x)=(2x^5-98)/(x-9)(x-1) is uniformly continuous on the interval(2,8)

I found it need to show the function is uniformly ctns in [2,8] then I can say (2,8)>=[2,8]

I am still confused how to show the function ctns in [2,8]. It is hard to use direct way to prove that.][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ0zN.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uniform continuity of $f(x) = \frac{2x^5-98}{(x-1)(x-9)}$ on $(2, 8)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2770139/uniform-continuity-of-fx-frac2x5-98x-1x-9-on-2-8)

Answer (score 1):

Every rational function is continuous on its domain. (The sum, difference, product, quotient of continuos unctions is continuous - just keep in mind that the quotient may have a smaller domain)

Comment: Thanks! For this question, I could say that because the function is continuous in [2,8],therefore it is uniformly continuous in [2,8]. And (2,8)>=[2,8], so it is uniformly ctns in (2,8). Could I do like this?